# how do I grab the names of products on a website when they are hidden with an overlay?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to grab all the names of devices on https://www.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet_devices. However, when I try grabbing the CSS selector with a gadget, there seems to be an overlay that doesn't enable you to select the header with the name.

I have tried various xpaths, but they seem to only return the first name or none at all when trying to get all of the names under an attribute. I've also tried

```
attribute_value = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="div_product_list_item_div_product_list_item_0"]/div[1]/div[2]/a/div[2]/span[1]')))
```

and going through item iterations, but the range is subject to change.

```
def phoneList():


    driver.get("https://www.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet_devices")

    attribute_value = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="productListWithFilters"]/div[3]'))).\
        get_attribute("class='rsx-product-name hidden-xs hidden-sm selectorgadget_suggested'")


    print(attribute_value)
```

I'm hoping to grab all device names and place them into a list no matter the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble getting all the elements with the data you were using, but try this instead:

Use find_elements_by_css_selector to find all the device name elements.  Loop through these, grab the text and add to a list.

```
list = []

cssSelector = '#productListWithFilters .rsx-product-list-product-name-group-bottom span:nth-child(1)'

devices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(cssSelector)

for i in devices:

     list.append(i.text)
```

Comment: slight error :) should be:
'#productListWithFilters .rsx-product-list-product-name-group-bottom span:nth-child(2)'
thank you that was very helpful